# Как работает range в for?

Tags: python, for

Вот допустим есть такой код:

```
for i in range(1,3,5):
    print(i)
```

Почему выводится в результате 1?Как это работает?

Comment: https://pythonz.net/references/named/range/

Comment: потому что `range(старт, стоп, шаг)`

Comment: А ты какой вывод ожидал?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 13):

Параметры `range(start, stop[, step])`:

1. С чего начинаем
2. На чём заканчиваем (не включительно)
3. Шаг

Поэтому в `range(1,3,5)` начинаем с 1, далее делаем +5 и выходим за границы 3 (6 >= 3). В итоге только единица печатается.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Answer (score 1):

Что такое `range()` в `for`.

```
for i in range(start,stop,step):
    print(i)
```

Это простой счетчик с началом `start`, концом `stop` и шагом `step`.

Почему в результате выводится `1`.

```
for i in range(1,3,5):
    print(i)
```

В примере `range(1,3,5)` счетчик считает от `1` до `3` с шагом `5`. Следующее число после `1` будет `6`, а оно больше `3`, поэтому оно не выводится.

*Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил. :)*

Comment: так вроде dIm0n уже объяснил, зачем второй ответ с тем же смыслом?